# while and if statements problem with my script?

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop, count

So I want to print "Wrong!" every time I get the wrong input. It works but when I type
the right input it still executes the "if" statement despite "guess.capitalize() != secret_word" being false. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
multiple methods is appreciated !

```
secret_word = "Dog"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess.capitalize() != secret_word and not out_of_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
        print("Wrong!")
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("You ran out of guesses")
else:
    print("You won!")
```

Comment: In the second snippet you have `guess = ...` directly followed by `guess = ...`. Guess (pun a little intended) which of the values `guess` will have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented the part of your code that is causing the bug:

```
while guess.capitalize() != secret_word and not out_of_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")# Here, the user can input correct word or wrong word
        guess_count += 1
        print("Wrong!") # The code goes down here, regardless of what the user input
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
```

Corrected version:

```
secret_word = "Dog"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while not out_of_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")# Here, the user can input correct word or wrong word
        if guess.lower() != secret_word.lower():
            guess_count += 1
            print("Wrong!") # The code goes down here, regardless of what the user input
        else:
            break
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("You ran out of guesses")
else:
    print("You won!")
```

Answer (score 0):

HI i think i understand what you are trying to do, i have read your code and restructred it to try give you your desired output.

```
secret_word = "Dog"
guess_count = 0

while True:
    if guess_count != 3:
        guess_count +=1
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ") 
        if guess.upper() == secret_word.upper():
            print("You Won!")
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong")
            continue
    else:
        print("You ran out of guesses")
        break
```

please let me know if this is not the output you are trying to get.